# Why doesn't doubleclick event fire after mouseDown event on same element fires?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a mousedown event and click event on a control. the mousedown event is used for starting dragdrop operation. The control I am using is a Dirlistbox.

```
 Private Sub Dir1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Dir1.MouseDown

    Dim lab As New Label
    lab.Text = Dir1.DirList(Dir1.DirListIndex)
    lab.DoDragDrop(lab, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub
```

But when i click on the control then only the mousedown event fires, click event does not get fire. 
If I comment out "lab.DoDragDrop(lab, DragDropEffects.Copy)" in the mousedown event then click event gets fire. 
what can I do so that both mousedown and click event gets fire when i click on the control?

Comment: I think `Click` event only fires if you release the mouse button without draging the pointer away. This could be your problem.

Comment: If `click` only fires without dragging the pointer away, try using `MouseUp` instead?

Comment: @SysDragon I am doing the same thing, even then the click event does not get fire.

Comment: @Pezzzz : I tried using the 'Mouseup' event, now click event gets fire but I am not able to use dragdrop operation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is by design.  The MouseDown event captures the mouse, Control.Capture property.  The built-in MouseUp event handler checks if the mouse is still captured and the mouse hasn't moved too far, then fires the Click event.  Trouble is that calling DoDragDrop() will cancel mouse capture.  Necessarily so since mouse events are now used to implement the drag+drop operation.  So you'll never get the Click nor the DoubleClick event.

Controls that both need to respond to clicks *and* drag+drop are a usability problem.  It is fixable however, what you need to do is ensure that the user has moved the mouse enough from the original mouse down location, *then* start the drag.  Make your code look like this:

```
Private MouseDownPos As Point

Private Sub Dir1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Dir1.MouseDown
    MouseDownPos = e.Location
End Sub

Private Sub Dir1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Dir1.MouseMove
    If e.Button And MouseButtons.Left = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim dx = e.X - MouseDownPos.X
        Dim dy = e.Y - MouseDownPos.Y
        If Math.Abs(dx) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width OrElse _
           Math.Abs(dy) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height Then
            '' Start the drag here
            ''...
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - the MouseDown --> MouseMove solution was reasonably obvious but I wasn't aware of the SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize information so that's really helpful :)

Comment: "Controls that both need to respond to clicks and drag+drop are a usability problem". One may want to handle drag and drop with left button, and right button click.

Answer (score 3):

for who needs c# version with drag and drop

```
    private Point MouseDownPos;
    private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseDownPos = e.Location;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            dynamic dx = e.X - MouseDownPos.X;
            dynamic dy = e.Y - MouseDownPos.Y;
            if (Math.Abs(dx) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width || Math.Abs(dy) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height)
            {
                DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                if (info.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    DataRowView view = (DataRowView)
                           dataGridView1.Rows[info.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;

                    if (view != null)
                        dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(view, DragDropEffects.Move);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've wasted days trying different readers' suggestions for solving this issue and this is the only one I found that actually worked.  Thank you!

Comment: This is not a translation of the VB code above--and includes references to objects (dataGridView1) that exist only in your own program...

Comment: Jazimov, who told you that it is the translation. It is the C# version to give you idea, nobody will do your job for you.