# Winform MouseDoubleClick event not firing after add MouseDown event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a User Control. It can be drag, also can be select. and need can be get single click, and double click.

At first I add the Selected property in the **Mouse Click event**. But It only get firing after **Mouse up**. Then I change My solution , I add it in **Mouse Down event**:

```
private void MyControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{             
      if (!Selected)
      {
            Selected = true;

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }
        else if(e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (null != MouseRightClick)
                MouseRightClick(model, this);
        }
      }                                 
}
```

But after that, **I can't get Mouse Double Click event anymore**:

```
private void MyControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // do something
}
```

**Update**
I saw the link you guys gave me, and I know the reason was:

> that calling DoDragDrop() will cancel mouse capture

But I still want to know, Is there any way to keep the `Drag` with `Double Click` events?

Comment: @CodeCaster, LoL. I update it. thank you.

Comment: The code you posted is not enough to reproduce the issue. Is `Selected` a property that does something, perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't doubleclick event fire after mouseDown event on same element fires?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731304/why-doesnt-doubleclick-event-fire-after-mousedown-event-on-same-element-fires)

Comment: @DonBoitnott Not quite a duplicate of that question. That one is in vb.net, this one is in c#, so the code will be different, it seems?

Comment: @Kaitlyn C# and vb both compile to a `CIL` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language. So vb or C# doesn't matter.

Comment: @Loathing my apologies then, I was under the impression that the way the code looks was different, therefore they are both different ;p

Comment: @Luaan, the ``Selected`` not do a big thing, It only change the User Control ``Border Style``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually after you know the reason as I said in my question update, It's very easy to fixed.
We should declare a variable for recognize draw:

```
private bool IsCanDraw = false;
```

Then you should add it in Mouse Down

```
private void MyControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Clicks != 1)
      {
          IsCanDraw = false;
      }
      else
     {
         IsCanDraw = true;
     }

     // your other code

}
```

Adn you need to change Mouse Move to :

```
private void MyControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left & IsCanDraw)
   {
        this.DoDragDrop(this, DragDropEffects.Move);
        // Disables IsCanDraw method until next drag operation
        IsCanDraw = false;
    }
}
```

As you see you can only do `DoDragDrop()` whene `IsCanDraw == true`
Then you Mouse Double Click event will fine.

---

The original ideas from(VB.NET) :

http://vbcity.com/forums/t/100458.aspx

http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/03/dodragdrop-prevent-doubleclick-event.html