# Datagridview allow double click edit while being able to drag and drop

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview where I need to be able drag and drop the file to a treeview in case they want to move the file to a different location, but also be able to double click in the first and 3 columns and still be able to modify the text in these columns for that row.

Currently my code to drag and drop the information from the datagridview into my treeview control works perfect.  However, since I'm using MouseDown I'm not able double click in the box to edit since its being caught.

Here is my code in the Datagridview MouseDown

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown
        If DataGridView1.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left And DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex < DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then

            dragedItemText = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            dragedItemEXT = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            dragedItemRowIndex = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex

            DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dragedItemText, DragDropEffects.Copy)

        End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION** - I want them to be able to edit column's 1 and 3, also be able to click and drag from ANY column to move it in the TreeView.  Is this even possible?
I'm assuming if it would be possible I need to setup some type of flag if they do a double mouse click then force the modification of the column's text?  And if this happens then make it so mousedown checks the flag and determines nothing in mouse down would trigger?
What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: This doesn't work.  I apologies I might not of been clear on my issue I'll modify it

Comment: See [Why doesn't doubleclick event fire after mouseDown event on same element fires?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14731304/719186)